# Finite sum of factorials, containing e, pi and bessel function

Tags: summation, pi, bessel-functions

In I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Rhyzhik's *table of integrals, series and products*, an interesting sum is given on page 2, formula 0.126:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n+k)!}{k!(n-k)!}=\sqrt{\frac{e}{\pi}}K_{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{equation}

Where $K_v(z)$ are the Bessel functions of imaginary argument, which are equal to the integral

\begin{equation}
K_v(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z\cosh t}\cosh vt\,dt
\end{equation}

How can one prove the sum? You can reference the article containing the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the first results comes from the fact that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n+k)!}{k!(n-k)!}x^k=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2 x}}}{\sqrt{\pi x}   } K_{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2 x}\right)$$

For $x=1$, this generates the sequence
$$\{1,3,19,193,2721,49171,1084483,28245729,848456353,28875761731,\cdots\}$$ which is $A001517$ in $OEIS$.

In the formula section, you could see an asymptotics proposed by Vaclav Kotesovec in $2014$

$$a_n \sim 2^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}\, e^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\, n^n$$ For $n=10$, this gives

$$a_{9}\sim\frac{101559956668416 \sqrt{2}}{e^{17/2}}=29223646682$$

The relative error is less than $1.00$% if $n >10$, less than $0.10$% if $n> 105$ and less than $0.01$% if $n>1042$.

Comment: How can the power series you mentioned be proved?